# Excel COM object - handling workbook close event

Tags: c++, excel, qt, com

I am automating an Excel window from a Qt application using `QAxObject`. I need to get notified when the Excel window is closed by the user.

Excel workbook COM object has an event `BeforeClose()` but handling it is not sufficient because it is fired before user is prompted to save changes, so user would cancel the close operation in save confirmation dialog. So, even `BeforeClose()` is fired, Excel window may not be closed.

There is another event `Deactivate()` which is fired when a workbook is deactivated. This is fired when a window is actually closed as well as when user switches to a different workbook. So handling it alone is also not sufficient.

The solution I am using currently is setting a bool variable `closing` to true when `BeforeClose()` is fired. When `Deactivate()` event handler is subsequently fired, I consider that Excel is closed only if `closing` is set true.

This needs one more thing, setting `closing` to false if user cancels close operation in save confirmation dialog. The method I used for that is starting a repeating timer in `BeforeClose()` and check `Visible` property of Excel COM object in the timer. `Visible` property is evaluated to false when a modal dialog such as save confirmation dialog is open. So I can set `closing` to `false` as soon as `Visible` property evaluated to `true` in timer.

Does anybody know a better way to get notified when Excel workbook is actually closed?

Comment: You are close. Instead just check if `Closing` is true in `Deactivate`. If so, then it's really closing. Set Closing to False at that point (if you're doing this at an application-level).

Comment: But Deactivate is not fired if user cancels close operation. So only way I found to reset `closing` to false is by using a timer.

Comment: You're right. Don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to bypass Excel's prompt like this (vb code):

```
Private Sub Handler_WorkbookBeforeClose(wb As Workbook, ByRef cancel As Boolean)

    If wb.Saved = False Then

        Dim answer As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Do you want to save the changes you made to " + wb.Name + "?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNoCancel)

        Select Case answer
            Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
                wb.Save()
            Case MsgBoxResult.No
                wb.Saved = True
            Case MsgBoxResult.Cancel
                cancel = True
                Exit Sub
        End Select

    End If

'Put here your code to be executed when workbook has been closed.

End sub
```