# Can IsWindowVisible() return false when an Excel window is open

Tags: c++, excel, qt, winapi, win32gui

I am automating an Excel window from my Qt application.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27586343/excel-com-object-handling-workbook-close-event) question, I was looking for a way to clearly identify when an excel window is closed. I got no answer for that from Stack Overflow.

I thought of a new way (other than the way I had described in my previous question) I can identify whether excel is closed. Here it is.

Get the window handle of excel using

```
excel->property("Hwnd").toInt();
```

Then use `IsWindowVisible()` WIN32 API to periodically check whether window is visible. If window is not visible, assume that excel is closed.

My question is, during normal usage of Excel, are there any scenarios where IsWindowVisible() will return false even if excel is not closed?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe IsWindow() function will be more suitable here? This function check existing of descriptor and it will return correct result when window really exist (show or hide, but exist). But don't forget that HWND is not unique for window and if window was closed and opened again, it will get new HWND

```
if(IsWindow(someHwnd)){
}else{
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633528(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: In my case, when user closes excel window, seems like window is not destroyed. IsWindow() returns true after user closes window. Excel instance is not actually terminated. If I kill it using task manager and again called IsWindow(), then it returns false.

Answer (score 1):

Excel isn't closed when the window still exists.

It is simply not visible, and you can automate Excel or WinWord and have documents open and Excel isn't visible at all.

This small VBS code starts excel makes it visible and hides it again. Your check will always return false when Excel is not visible but still "not closed".

```
Set oXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
MsgBox "Created but not visible"
oXL.Visible = True
MsgBox "Created but and visible"
oXL.Visible = False
MsgBox "Created but not visible again "
Set oXL = Nothing
MsgBox "Closed (Terminated) now"
```

In fact the only way would be to check when the window is really no longer existing (IsWindow).

If you are referring to a specific document it may be easier to check if the document is still listed in the IROT table. If not. Excel has closed it.

PS: You should define "Closed" in a more precise way.

Comment: What I do in my Qt app is putting some data to excel and making it visible. After that, user is free to do anything but my Qt app needs to get notified when user closes the window. I cannot use IsWindow because it returns true even if the user closes the window (Seems like window is not destroyed when user closes). Can you give me some more information about IROT table you mentioned and how to access it?

Comment: As long as you hold a COM pointer to the Excel object this worksheet (or whatever you access) is never closed and terminated. Look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms695276(v=vs.85).aspx There is/was a program IROTVIEW in the SDK that you can use to look what is registered. Create a moniker to the check if the file is in use. That is the way GetObject in VBS works. You can use it too.

Comment: @LahiruChandima: The common problem with `IsWindow` is that it just tells you whether the HWND is a window handle, not whether it's still the same (Excel) window that is was previously. A HWND is not a GUID, they're recycled.